# Использование ссылки вместо кнопки

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Сразу скажу что использую гайд https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, и все, о чем я не пишу здесь, скорее всего является практически точной копией из гайда.
В данном случае мне необходимо сделать вместо кнопки из формы `form.submit` ссылку.

```
 <p>
    <%= link_to "Add", articles_path, :id => "create_article",
      :class => "inbox-sf-add-btn tip", :method => :post %>
    <%= form.submit %>
 </p>
```

Ссылка также импровизированная, позаимствованная из гугла. Выполняет вроде бы то, что мне необходимо, но не собирает данные из формы. Полностью форма выглядит так:

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= link_to "Add", articles_path, :id => "create_article",
      :class => "inbox-sf-add-btn tip", :method => :post %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Кнопка, которая находится в форме рабочая и мне также необходимо сделать таковой и ссылку. Но ссылка не собирает данные из формы и при нажатии выходит ошибка `param is missing or the value is empty: article`. Сама функция в контроллере:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title)
    end
```

Comment: Ссылка и не должна собирать данные из формы, это ведь просто ссылка. Зачем вам ссылка вместо кнопки, которая специально предназначена для отправки формы?

Comment: Можно сделать "пустую" ссылку и навесить на нее `.submit();`, но, действительно, зачем это нужно? Как вариант можете просто стилизовать кнопку под ссылку - `background-color: transparent; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; box-shadow: unset; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;` и т.д.